# ListView Highlight Issue

Tags: android

I'm programming using an adapter for list view and I want it to be such that when the user touches a list view element, it remains highlighted. I succeeded using the code below. But due to android recycling the layouts for smooth performance, when I click on row 1, row 11, 21, 31 etc get highlighted too. Then if I scroll down, row 1 isn't selected anymore, but rows 4, 14, 24 etc are highlighted. This is the code I used

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row, collection);            
onelist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
onelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        str1 = (String)onelist.getItemAtPosition(position);
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
        Toast.makeText(context, str1 + " clicked in Fragment " + fragmentNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(lastColored != null)
        {
            lastColored.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            lastColored.invalidate();
        }
        lastColored = v;
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 181, 229));

     };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried extending BaseAdapter and using selectors for backgorund on listview elements?
Tutorial about BaseAdapter: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/ 
And some stuff about selectors: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What about using a list<> or array[] in the activity to record which item should be highlight, and set items highlight in the getview().

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector for the ListView row with attribute [`android:state_activated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3astate_activated). I had recently created a demo example for the same just few days back. You can [download](https://github.com/lalit3686/ListSelectorActivity) and check it out from my github.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Background resource in your Adapter class of `getView()` method . As `Pawel Cala` told use Selector for that view.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, You should records which items should be highted. and remember to clear because of convert view.